# Is there an appropriate security provider for the DOM document type when using Android API Version >=24?

Tags: android, dom, xml-signature, android-api-levels

I've been trying to build XML documents using the javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory library.
When instantiating the class, I need to pass a security provider as the argument of the getInstance() function, i.e.

XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", provider)

Now, normally, the provider would be found in the apache santuario library i.e. XMLDSigRI():

```
private val xmlSigFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI())
```

However, the library is using the java.util.Base64 class, which doesn't work for Android API Version < 26.

I have tried using the BouncyCastle security provider, which does not work for whatever reason, since I am getting this error when trying to run it:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.NoSuchMechanismException: no such mechanism type: DOM for provider BC
```

And the same for SpongyCastle. (provider SC)

Is there any way to find a working security provider for Android API Version >= 24?
If not, what could be the possible workaround here?

Tried using every single one of the listed security providers which I got with this chunk:

```
        for(p in Security.getProviders()) {
            Log.d("PROVIDER NAME", p.name)
            Log.d("PROVIDER INFO", p.info)
        }
```

BouncyCastle and SpongyCastle included.
Tried forking and changing the whole library so that the java.util.Base64 class gets replaced with another Base64 class, which proved difficult and I gave up on it(for now).
Trying to find a normal security provider which works with API < 26

Comment: Might be worth considering effort vs reward here. There are a tiny portion of users still using Android 7.x (which is now almost 8 years old).

Comment: The problem is that I’m working on the project for a client who has cca 200 devices running android 7.1. 
Possible solution to the problem could be simply leaving all of it to the server, which is getting more and more likely, it could possibly even be better since the load wouldn’t be on the physical device(which is much weaker than a normal modern smartphone) but rather on the server. Was just wondering how I could solve it since it was really bugging me